# how to automatically accept a popup message when separating data into columns using VBA?

Tags: vba, popup, cells

I am trying to separate a data in a cell into columns, I do it with vba but when running the code a popup message shows up asking me to accept, I don't need to accept something since I'm running the code to get what I want.
this is the code:

```
Sub Separaren4()

 Range("AZ3").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AZ3"), 
 DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
 FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(29, 1)), _
 TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPp3U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

before your code and set it to True after.

```
Sub Separaren4()
Application.EnableEvents = False
 Range("AZ3").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AZ3"), 
 DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
 FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(29, 1)), _
 TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the field before occupying it

```
Sub Separaren4()
    With Range("AZ3")
        .Resize(,4).EntireColumn.Clear 
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(29, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
   End With
End Sub
```